# TKinter grid causes program not to run

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

I'm new to python and TKinter. I'm trying to write a program with a basic gui. I wanted basic control over the layout and tried to implement grid. For some reason when I run the code using grid, no window comes up, if I comment that line out, it works fine, but things aren't where I want them. Could anyone give me a clue as to what I'm doing wrong, and more importantly what I'm not understanding?

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def createWidgets(self):    
        self.Name_label = Label(text="Name")    
        self.Name_label.pack({"side": "left"})
        self.Name_label.grid(row=2, column=1)#If I comment this line out, it works.

        self.Name = Entry(self)
        self.Name.pack({"side": "right"})
        #self.Name.grid(column=1, row=0)

        self.QUIT = Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit

        self.QUIT.pack(side="bottom")

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master = root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use both pack and grid. 
 Also you should add your items to your grid

Comment: To clarify: you cannot use both pack and grid _in the same container_ (eg: same frame). You can use them both in the same app, just not together with more than one widget that shares the same parent.